# "catch" push notifications in Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want to add an integrated chat in my app and i'm trying to do so with parse.

The guide on how to send push notifications in their docs is very specific but i can't find a good explanation on how to "turn" the push notification that one has received into a text View,even thou the user didn't clicked on the notification..

Another question, "channels" is basically specifies who will see my message,right? i mean, if i'm subscribed to a specific channel, only who is subscribed to this channel will see my message and not all the users who registered to the app,right?

How can i do that?, there is no explanation at all in their docs..

Answer (score 0):

You can easily subclass `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver` to tweak the behavior of your application without foregoing all of the built-in features. Put your new class in the manifest instead default ParsePushBroadcastReceiver. You can react to push notification events by overriding any of `onPushReceived`, `onPushOpen`, or `onPushDismiss`.